# baked normal map gets unwanted inverted rectangular spot

Tags: normals, texture-baking, normal-map

using Blender internal for baking, high poly is the same model, but with Bevel modifier limited by angle, the model is manually unwrapped.

problematic spot is visible under the roof of the house model and on it's normal map.
[image]

by the way, i'm doing it to get smoothed corners without adding extra geometry. if there's a better way of doing it - i'd like to know it.

[.blend file here](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=43977)

Answer (score 1):

Probably inverted normals or slighty overlaped faces on house corner.

BTW: I recommend bevel edges (2 or 3 loops) if you want smooth edges. Or let them be sharp. Also in case you want use this in mobile application. Few hundreds faces more does not have influence in performance and look a lot better. Is impossible make nice smooth edge from 90° angle :-)

Comment: i checked the normals - they seem to be fine. also haven't found any overlapping faces. had a hole at the bottom of a model - thought maybe closing it will do anything  - nope, results are still the same.

Comment: oh, yes, and i am using Bevel modifier with several segments.

Comment: i keep sending new comments instead of making a new line =/

wanted to also ask why are you saying 90 degree corners cannot be smoothed? i do not want them to look flat, i want them to look slightly rounded instead of perfectly sharp, that's why i'm using smooth shading, bevelling and baking a normal map with all that.

also, this house is an example - the models i'm actually going to use have a lot more vertices, so simply bevelling everything does not sound like a good idea.

Comment: About 90° corners - do as you thing. :-)

Comment: :-)))))))))))))